# Blender better visibility for wireframes

Tags: wireframe

I am trying to follow this simple tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zkg7Ol2jEjs

But I have found that when I change to wireframe view the object becomes completely transparent instead of a transparent gray

How it looks in the video
[image]

How it looks for me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Wireframe mode, this is a X-ray mode. You can toggle it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, or by clicking on this button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alt+Z to toggle x-ray or see picture for button in 3d viewport(upper right)
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!